# Mach-O binary editor for OSX?

Tags: macos, editor, osx-leopard, mach-o

py-macholib does not work properly on osx (using darwin ports). I have not found any other alternative.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe someone could help if you would tell what exactly it is that you are trying to accomplish. The more precise the question the more helpful the answer(s).

Answer (score 7):

Try this: [MachOView](http://machoview.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: MachOView cannot edit files, but you can use it to find offsets and then edit the data with HexFiend.

Comment: you can edit the hex content in the second column.